# Three.js can not load texture for mtl & obj files (parts with image textures are not showing)

Tags: javascript, three.js, textures

I have problems with using three.js.

when I load a .obj & .mtl file using OBJLoader & MTLLoader, I got this: 
[image: Rendered using THree.js],

but It should look like this:
 [image]

**Which means that the texture is not loaded**.

I just using the typical code of load obj+mtl:

```
    var mtlLoader = new THREE.MTLLoader();
    mtlLoader.setPath('obj/');
    mtlLoader.load('74.mtl', function(materials) {
        materials.preload();
        var objLoader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
        objLoader.setMaterials(materials);
        objLoader.setPath('obj/');
        objLoader.load('74.obj', function(object) {
            scene.add(object);
        });
    });
```

My project folder looks like this:

[image]

I got this message, when I load the html page in chrome: `[.WebGL-08E80F00]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_OPERATION : glDrawArrays: attempt to access out of range vertices in attribute 2`

[image]

obj, mtl, jpg files are uploaded on: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1bYbzR57CYZj1JxyMiCjrCx331nyb78a1 as well as https://pan.baidu.com/s/1jjWCezpXywaEOMKz9djkIw

If I just remove the `map_Kd stone_1.jpg` in .mtl file, It works fine with the ambient and diffuse light. I also tried looking deep into OBJLoader.js, and it seems it load the image successfully.

I tried a lot of ways, but none of them work...and I really don't know what is going on.

Thanks you so much!!!

Comment: Did you finally fix this issue? I'm having the same issue, my mtl file is not being applied. Thank you!

Comment: I did not. However, I found an alternative solution that is transforming .obj and .mtl to .gltf format. see https://github.com/AnalyticalGraphicsInc/obj2gltf